# Apache, Django and wsgi, No module named 'encodings'

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi, ubuntu-18.04

I've looked through many stack overflow questions with the same issues, but none of them solved my issue. I'm trying to deploy Django on AWS - Ubuntu 18.04 using Apache and WSGI.

When running my website with Django's servers on port 8000, everything works fine. Then when I attempt to run on apache I get the following error in my logs.

```
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
(2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi: Unable to stat Python home /var/www/html/projects/venv
Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path
and access permissions for whole of the path.
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

As it says clearly mod_wsgi and Python 3 are configured. I am using a virtual environment. My project is located at:

```
/var/www/html/project/venv/mysite
```

My Apache conf file is configured as:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/projects/venv/mysite/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/var/www/html/projects/venv/mysite python-home =/var/www/html/projects/venv
WSGIProcessGroup mysite
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/projects/venv/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

Alias /static /var/www/html/projects/venv/mysite/polls/static
<Directory /var/www/html/projects/venv/mysite/polls/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. I don't fully understand what the error means. I have Python installed in my Venv. There is a file pyenv.conf which reads

```
home = /usr
implementation = CPython
version_info = 3.6.9.final.0
virtualenv = 20.0.20
include-system-site-packages = false
base-prefix = /usr
base-exec-prefix = /usr
base-executable = /usr/bin/python3
```

I'm wondering if this base-executable path being different than my python path in the apache config file is causing problems, but I'm not sure exactly what I need to do from here (or if this is even part of the problem. I believe permissions should not be the issue since I added all of my files within the var/www/html folder.

Update: I added the recommended permissions to all files in the chain and that didn't change anything.

Any advice is appreciated.